# Scale a rotated rectangle along the rectangle's horizontal axis

Tags: android, animation

I have a rectangle in Android that is rotated by 45 degrees and I want to get an animation that scales up rectangle from 0 to 100% along the horizontal axis of the rotated rectangle.

Below is an image of a horizontal rectangle and the animation that I have for a plane rectangle. I want to achieve the same, but when the rectangle tilted at an angle.

[image]

The pink rectangle inside should grow in size so that the height of the rectangle remains unchanged and width increases from 0 to full size

My layout:

```
<RelativeLayout
  android:rotation="45"
  android:visibility="visible"
  android:id="@+id/rel_button"
  android:layout_centerInParent="true"
  android:layout_width="300dp"
  android:layout_height="150dp"
  android:background="@color/colorAccent">
</RelativeLayout>
```

My code related to animation:

```
Animation animation = new ScaleAnimation(0.0f,1f,1,1,ScaleAnimation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF,0.5f,ScaleAnimation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f);
animation.setDuration(3000);
btn.startAnimation(animation);
```